# How can I decide relay on-off periods depending on the PID output

Tags: temperature, pid-controller

In my PID project, I am using discrete time PID formula as follows.

u(k)=u(k-1)+Kc * [(e(k) – e(k-1)) + (Ts*e(k))/Ti + Td/Ts * (e(k) – 2*e(k-1) + e(k-2))

As you know PID output increases over time if the actual point goes above the set point. I am using relays to give input to the system. Because of the thermal inertia, output increases even I turn off the relays. The main quesiton in my mind is, how can I determine the on-off periods of relays depending on the PID output? For example, in the second on period of relay, when should i turn off the relay to avoid overshoot?
[image]

Comment: Can you take the output of the PID and use it to set the pulse width in a PWM signal?

Comment: @Tyler - are you suggesting that the OP try to PWM a relay?!?

Comment: @brhans Is it a mechanical or solid state relay?

Comment: The problem is, the relay will not provide a proportional control, and the heat load will not be equal either. So the control will not be a linear system. PID's can still work somewhat with on-off controllers but with a lot more error.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram shows on-off control, not PID. This is behaving rather like a thermostat. Your P is set to max and your I and D terms to zero.

> As you know PID output increases over time if the actual point goes above the set point.

If your application is a heating one then your output decreases if the actual (process value) exceeds the setpoint.

> I am using relays to give input to the system.

OK.

> Because of the thermal inertia, output increases even I turn off the relays.

Be careful with your thinking and wording. I think you mean to say, "Because of the thermal inertia **temperature** continues to increase even after I turn off the relays. (If your relays have turned the output off then it's off.) This is a common problem but it can be reduced or eliminated by proper tuning.

> The main question in my mind is, how can I determine the on-off periods of relays depending on the PID output? For example, in the second on period of relay, when should I turn off the relay to avoid overshoot?

You let the PID controller do it.

[image]

*Figure 1.*

Read through Eurotherm's [PID control made easy](https://www.eurotherm.com/en/temperature-control/pid-control-made-easy/) twice and then try using their technique to set yours up.

---

Update from comments:

[image]

*Figure 2.*

> As shown in the red rectangle, X<sub>osc</sub> = 8°C and t<sub>osc</sub> = 225 s. So I choose P = 16, I = 337.5 and D = 67.5. In the graph, I turned on my relays when error is positive.

This is not how PID is used. You are not using the PID output correctly.

In any case, you do not seem to have followed the Eurotherm procedure correctly.

[image]

*Figure 3.*

Set your PID for on-off (thermostat control) as shown in the upper graph of Figure 3 and then take the measurements for x<sub>osc</sub> and t<sub>osc</sub>.

> I am thinking that I should decide when to open my relay not just looking at the error but output.

No, the PID controller does this. The output (heating in your case) should be proportional to the PID output. When using relay control that means you have to vary the duty cycle (the amount of 'on' time) in proportion to the PID output.

> So how should I write my algorithm?

- Create a duty cycle timer, \$ t_{cycle} \$. The relays should be able to handle being switched every 10 s and your system's response time is relatively long so that should give good control.
- Then calculate the on-time by \$ t_{on} = u(k) \times t_{cycle} \$ where *u(k)* is the percentage out of the PID loop.

For example, if the PID output is 26% and you are running a 10 s duty cycle then the relay should be on for 2.6 s out of 10 s.

Let the PID do its work directly. Stop trying to override it.

Comment: Can you add the control signal to the relay, along with the graph? I think that's the magic missing here. I'm not sure how you would over-damp the response in this system without pwm'ing the relay, which is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Transistor.

Comment: You are right. I am aware that this graph shows an on-off control with Kp 1 Kd 0 and Ki 0.  But for example, in the first cycle I am turning on my relays and start to heat up. When I reach theset point, I am turning off the relay. Because of the inertia, temperature increases for a while. So I am waiting  until the actual temperature decreases until set temp. I am turning on the relays but they give slow response to the system. So that temperature decreases even if the relays on. So I have to add I and D parameters and decide when to open relays to get min oscillating and stable graph.

Comment: Did you do the "Popular Method (Rule of Thumb)" (if not then please do) and what did you get for \$ X_{osc}\$ and \$ t_{osc} \$ and what values did you then choose for *P*, *I* and *D*? Can you show a plot of the resultant response?

Comment: As shown in the red rectangle, Xosc 8C and tosc 225sec.
So I choose P = 16 I = 337.5 and D = 67.5. In the graph below, I turned on my relays when error is positive.
I am thinking that I should decide when to open my relay not just looking at the error but output.
So for example, I should turn on my relays as shown in the black, so that my graph follows a path as shown in red.Image is here -> https://pasteboard.co/IwRTCfR.jpg

Comment: So how should I write my algorithm?

`if(Output < 0)
        Relays ON 60sec
 Relays OFF 0sec
else
 Relays ON 0sec
 Relays OFF 60sec`
or

`if(Output < X)
 Relays ON 50sec
 Relays OFF 10sec
else if(Output < Y)
 Relays ON 30sec
 Relays OFF 30sec
else
 Relays ON 0sec
 Relays OFF 60sec`
or do you have any suggestion?

Comment: See the update. Post all the additional information including the graph into your question rather than have it sprinkled through the comments where nobody will find it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But I didn't understand the percentage concept. I am keeping tcycle 20sec. What is 26%? Error / Total Output ? Instant Output / Total Output?

Comment: I got it! It is Error / Proportional Band Size.

Comment: 26%, in my example, is the output of the PID, *u(k)*. You really need to stop looking inside the PID loop at the error. You are only concerned with the PID output value and this determines the amount of power to be applied to the system. If the PID output is 26% and you are running 20 s cycle then the on-time is 5.2 s. Can you get the PID output to give you a 0 to 100% signal? (You need to clamp it to minimum of 0 and maximum of 100% if the PID calculation causes it to go outside that range.

Answer (score 0):

At first look your PID algo seems OK, but I haven't debugged it, visually it looks good to me. You have to link the PID output to the PWM generator that switches the heater on and off.

From your question is not clear if the heater is supplied with DC or AC, or what is the switching element: it is an AC SSR, transistor, relay....

Do not forget to add the limiter right below your PID code, it serves also for anti-windup for the integral term.

```
if u(k) > 100% then
   u(k) = 100%
elseif u(k) < 0% then
   u(k) = 0%
```

If you have an AC SSR or relay, then a suitable PWM cycle is from 5s to 10s respectively. When using a relay make sure to introduce some non-linear element to avoid short switching pulses, for example:

```
if u(k) > 95% then   
    pwm = 100% 
elseif u(k) < 5% then   
    pwm = 0%
```

Note that % units are just for representation.

Comment: Heaters are supplied in AC. Relays are standard, they are not SSR. So I have to keep relay switching lifetime in my mind. As you said, I have to link my Output with PWM. But how? Should I find a ratio between the output and relay's on time? To avoid overshoot, how should I decide the PWM or in other words relay's on-off time?

Comment: PWM period is fixed, my suggestion was 10s, then you control the duty time ratio. You can do the sampling and calculation of PID with same period. You can download some datasheets or manuals of industrial temperature PID controllers to get an idea. They all work on this principle.